# Relay SMTP server

Tags: smtp

I am not a server administrator, but know my way around *nix and shell

Right now my web server is set up to relay to an e-mail address that does not exists.
How can I change it.

Thanks for any answers or help, and please forgive my bad english.

best Regards

Jon

Comment: By the way my php.ini sendmail_path is /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
And as you guess I can't send e-mail from a simple PHP script. I get no errors, but the mail never arrives.

Comment: Tell us more: what SMTP server is installed  (if any), what does its configuration look like, etc.

Comment: How do I find out what SMTP server which is installed?

Comment: telnet localhost 25 if one of the following has output

socklist | grep 25 or netstat -an | grep 25

Comment: netstat -an | grep 25 gives me this:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out:

```
/etc/aliases
```

That is typically one of the first places to check for email forwarding. If that doesn't help, try:

```
grep -r bad_email@address.com /etc
```

Perhaps that will show you which file you need to edit.

Comment: And if you do change `/etc/aliases`, most mail servers need you to run `newaliases` in order to register the changes.

Comment: aliases did not tell me much and I could not find the bad_email@address.com
I guess the it is a common Red Hat with Apache, PHP and MySQL setup, and I guess I am using sendmail since the php.ini file indicates so :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that mail from the web application running on your server is going to a non-existent address?  If so, the address will probably be configured either in the config files for the PHP/Apache application, or somewhere in the database used by it.  Try issuing:

```
grep -r nonexistent@address.com
```

in whichever directory the website files are in.

Comment: Yes, the mail from the web application(PHP using mail() ) is not received.

I've tried to add the -r in the fifth mail() parameter and the mail works from some locatoins.